# VBA Excel 2003 disconnecting to DB object

Tags: database, excel, vba, connection

I have watched this code execute. It executes the 'close' then the 'setting to nothing'. Then  it returns to the the 'close' and throws an error 91 "Object variable with block not set".

```
Public Sub closeItDown()
   ' CLEAN UP and SHUT DOWN
   cnxRPTRS.Close
   Set cnxRPTRS = Nothing
End Sub
```

I have used this code in many 'applications'. However this time I am using it and the Start routine several times connecting and disconnecting to the DB. This is to clear all the Temp tables and start with a different set of circumstance. This is to get around another problem and I just want to finish.

```
Set cnxRPTRS = New ADODB.Connection
cnxRPTRS.Open strForCNX 'Open the connection.
...
```

The first time through there is no problem on the Second time is when the problem happens.

Comment: try adding `DoEvents` between `.Close` and `Set = Nothing` Maybe it did not have enough time to close the connection..

Comment: I had a go with this and It same results

Answer (score 0):

If you call close everything related that object (Conn, Command, and RS objects are set to nothing). Specific rules are in help.

Don't do this

```
Set cnxRPTRS = Nothing
```

and don't that

```
Set cnxRPTRS = New ADODB.Connection
```

What are you trying to do, make a good boy of you, do you know where it's at.

Just close and (re) rs.open. For Command object check that Conn propery is set.